# Floating buttons

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to make an Android app that will have buttons floating on other apps like Messenger does. I can't into Java, so it must be in Cordova. How to do this? Some plugins? And no - it can't be a button to switch between 2 apps.

Comment: http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-add-material-design-floating-action-button-to-ionic-framework-apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that he needs is to make a floating app not a menu, as in native app Androidhttps://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531 , So Sorry i have not idea en cordova